# Use separate DB Context for Identity 2 and application models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, single-sign-on, asp.net-identity-2

I am using VS.2017 with EF6 with ASP.NET Core template to create a website. I would like to know whether it is really possible to use two different Application DB contexts on my web application.

Since it is the default template with Individual Accounts, it already comes with a standard migration to create the Identity 2 repository on the database. It also has the default ApplicationDBContext although I don't see any entity being exposed in the default ApplicationDBContext (should it not expose User?)

I am sure many will ask WHY. I want to have the default application DB context (context 1) for Identity 2.x and then context 2 for my application's models so that I can separate them.

The idea behind being that the Identity Context will be hosted in a separate database for Single Sign On but only modified to associate a user account with a specific web application site.

**UPDATE 1**
As stated there will be multiple domains using the same "Identity Server" BUT I do not need to be able to use the same user to automatically login to the other site. In other words, the Identity Server is a shared database to keep identity data but each domain is aware of its own users (and ignores uses of the other domains).

For that reason the first DB context would be for the "Identity Server" database and teh second DB context for application models not related to identity.

Comment: Yes, if you are not relating the Identity tables it's perfectly feasible. Even if you need to relate, there are workarounds like storing the key to the user table and doing a join when needed.

Comment: But how do I specify in my asp.net application that Identity views use the Identity DB context while let the other controllers use the separate application DB context? that is not clear to me.

Comment: @LordofScripts you can have as many DBContexts as you like. You can rename your `ApplicationDbContext` into `IdentityContext` and create another `DbContext` as you wish.

Comment: You can even extract your `IdentityContext` into a nuget library and add it to all your projects where it is needed - will make your life a lot easier for your scenario

Comment: @trailmax good hints, but how does the account controller knows it has to use the IdentityContext class and the other controllers use the MyDbContext instead? there must be a place where that is indicated.

Comment: `MyDbContext myContext = new MyDbContext(); var identityContext = new IdentityContext();` This is a class. Work with it as you work with any class you work with. Look into Dependency Injection and inject the right context where it is needed.